# Duplicate class Error on Android Build, cause by two same name package installed in React Native (Expo) App

Tags: android, react-native, expo

During the Android build process I get Error said  `A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction`

and then I realize the key error message is `Type org.reactnative.maskedview.BuildConfig is defined multiple times:`

in my `package.json`  I have two `masked-view`  (Which is import by another two packages I am using, I did google what is the diff between these two masked view, seems like there no different just the same package in different place. )

```
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.9",
```

So my question is, by understanding now what cause the problem. what should I do in this case?

1. I could replace  two packages import these two different masked-view, to making sure just one masked-view in my project. but since these two packages are already used in lot places in my project, so this is the last solution I would consider.
2. patch-package, I would like to modify either one of package to make sure they are import the same masked-view(since they have no different.) -> this does working as I except, but seems like `patch-package` won't record any changes to the package.json file in those package, so this seems like not good enough to me.

So, by posting this question here just want to see if there any better solutions will come up for this kind situation, and also i am curious why there was no any error occupy in `IOS`.